# Ubuntu LTS Desktop version for Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

I went to Ubuntu's website and looked for the .img file for my Raspberry Pi 400. I can only find the desktop version of 20.10, which is not a LTS and not the one I want. Where can I find the 20.04.1 DESKTOP (not server or core) to flash? I have Balena Etcher for MacOS and I am going to flash my 512GB SanDisk MicroSD Card. I can only find the server and core builds of 20.04.1, but not the desktop.

Also, will this OS work fine on the 400? I tried it on my 3B and the desktop environment takes all the resources on 1GB of RAM. I know the Gnome DE (what Ubuntu uses) takes a lot of resources, hopefully it will work fine as my main PC on my Pi 400. I have high hopes for this OS, as I am ready to move on from Ubuntu MATE and want to use normal Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No official Ubuntu Desktop Image for Raspberry Pi was released for Ubuntu 20.04. However, you can install the desktop on top of the server edition.
Install the server image and enter the command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

and reboot.
(You may first need to run `sudo apt update` in a fresh installation)

---

Desktop images for Raspberry Pi are available for later versions of Ubuntu. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1438552/124466) answer.

Answer (score 2):

2 GHz single core processor. 2 GiB RAM (system memory) 10 GB of hard drive space.May 14, 2020. That is the min requirements for 20.04. Also 20.04 is an LTS that is the only 20.04 DESKTOP version.

Comment: There is 20.04 Server and Core, I am looking for the Desktop

Comment: Did a small edit to my answer I guess I was not clear.

Comment: You're fine. Hope this will be fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

### With the release of Ubuntu 22.04, more official desktop versions for the Raspberry Pi have become available.

**I used to use Ubuntu Mate 22.04 desktop on my Pi 4 with 4GB RAM.** Today I switched to Vanilla flavored Ubuntu 22.04, It is working great for me, plus it is nice to be using an OS I am familiar with.

I have heard that it is a little slower than Mate, but now I am not sure that is true. It is a keeper.

Download https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi image for Raspberry Pi and use Rufus or Etcher in Windows or mkusb, dd or Gnome-Disks in Ubuntu to flash to your micro SD card.

Comment: Maybe you could include the steps on how to install Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry Pi? I don't believe this is documented in the official guides (and if they are, I don't know where). 

Comment: @Artur Meinild: Basically only one step, flash the image to micro SD card and boot. Answer has been edited.

Comment: I think I get it - but you linked to the official image, not the Mate image.. I made it more clear, hope it's ok.

Comment: @Artur Meinild: See https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ for details I do not want to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: The question was about Ubuntu 20.04.1 Desktop, not Mate.

Comment: Sorry then I don't understand your answer... Archisman already said it, and so did I in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1348561/1066942). The link you insert downloads Ubuntu 22.04.1 for Pi - there never was a 20.04 desktop image for the RasPi.

Comment: That was back in June 2021, Your answer is out of date. 20.04 also worked for me without problem.

Comment: Care to join the Downboat to discuss this??

Comment: It is getting late in Sri Lanka. I will check Raiders of the Lost Downboat in the morning. Maybe try 20.04 on Pi 4 beforehand.

Comment: Oops, Sorry, I have been talking about 22.04 Desktop, not 20.04.

Comment: Yes, but the question is still about 20.04 - which is what I was talking about, and probably why I was confused..

Comment: The OP says that he wants an LTS version of Ubuntu, 22.04 is the best option available.

Comment: I've edited the question title, and inserted a paragraph in your answer to add more context.

Comment: I have linked your answer in my answer.