# Is Ubuntu 20.04 desktop for raspberry pi 4 no longer available?

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop on my Raspberry Pi 4, but the ISO image is not found on the official website.

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Is this image unavailable already ?

Comment: Other option is to try Ubuntu MATE - https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/download/ or Debian 10 - https://raspi.debian.net/tested-images/ .

Comment: Not that you're wrong or anything, but my answer actually sums it up rather simply.

Comment: There is an Ubuntu Desktop for Raspberry-Pi -> https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi (scroll down - Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 - should work for all Raspberry-Pi 3 and 4)

Comment: Do you need 20.04 or will 22.04 work for you? https://ubuntu.com/blog/whats-new-for-raspberry-pi-ubuntu-22-04-lts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There never was a specific desktop version of Ubuntu 20.04 for Raspberry Pi. Instead, you have to install the server version of Ubuntu 20.04, and when that is installed, you install the desktop environment with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: thank you! This worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to your question: Please note that on the official download page that you refer to you will not find every possible Ubuntu version there is. For that have a look at [Ubuntu releases](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/).
There it is quite easy to find e.g. a 64 bit AArch64 server for Ubuntu 20.04.1 or what ever your heart desire.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you may be looking in the wrong place, this is what you're looking for:
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/21.04/release/ubuntu-21.04-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz

Comment: OP asked about 20.04, not 21.04. 

Comment: Please 1. make sure you are answering the question, 2. fix broken link(s)